# Read the Yaml File

Tags: java, android, yaml

I have added the jyaml 1.3 jar in project and try to read the yaml file but unable to read the file.

I am getting the object value in below line but unable to read that value.

```
Object object = Yaml.load(new File("/mnt/sdcard/file.yaml"));
```

Comment: Please, show what you've tried

Comment: Did you try to read how to use that ` jyaml 1.3 jar` library?

Comment: I'd suggest using [Snake YAML](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml) instead of jYaml (as it's not maintained for a lot of time now).